# How do we feel about "Identify this puzzle" questions?

Tags: discussion

At some point there will probably be questions asked that consist mainly of a photo and "What is this puzzle called?"

Are these questions on-topic?

My main concern is that they are not easily Googlable, which detracts from Stack Exchange's policy of being an information storehouse in addition to a Q&A network.

They could prove to be quite interesting though, and introduce people to new puzzles.

Comment: Without taking a position (yet?) on this, once such a question gets a few answers, it becomes a lot easier to Google. And Google image search is improving constantly as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be tempted to say yes, at least in our early days, as there should be a definite answer, which will fit the SE framework.

Your point about google is quite relevant though.

I think google image search will be able to use questions that are based on an image, but we should probably look at how we tag/describe questions which are image only. Worth thinking about.

tl;dr - yes, at least during beta. It might get questions asked about the identified puzzles.

Comment: Agreed, we should definitely allow them, but they should be as well described textually as reasonably possible.

Comment: Could the answer work in reverse? Where the answer and related links are found when googling, giving value to the provided image?